Sizing bypass closet doors for non-standard rough openings
I am having drywall done and ordering doors. The only one that is throwing me off is the closet.
Closet A has a rough opening of 61.75". The closet is preferred to be bypass doors mission style.  I originally planned to do two 30" doors for closet A.
However, it appears I have erred on my rough in opening since the door jambs are a total of 1.25 inches on each closet.  Then it is recommended to have 1" overlay on the bypass doors.
A 30" door slab is actually 29.8125", two doors combined is actually 59.625 inch, minus 1 inch overlay is 58.625 inches.  This would give me 61.75 - 1.25 jamb - 58.625 door with overlay = 1.875" too much of a rough opening.
The easiest fix I can think of is for me to add a 2x4 (1.5") overlay to one side, then a 1x4 (.75") to the other side and hide it with trim.  Does this sound right or am I not thinking of this clearly?
I am trying to think of the lesser evil of a solution.  Since the closet doors have a design and are not flat it is more obvious the more overlay they have.  Not sure how much overlay it will be horrible, but estimating 2" overlay is tolerable.

Bypass = sliding?

OP states they are bypass doors.

@RMDman and I'm asking what that means—I've never heard the term "bypass" related to doors.

@Huesmann,  Bypass doors are on an overhead track and do slide. They are usually used as closures for long wall cabinets.  They are called bypass because the doors are mounted in an offset allowing  the doors to pass in front  or behind the other.  All bypass doors are sliders, but not all sliders are bypass.

In my experience the interrelation of two bypass doors at the overlap doesn't draw the eye, even in a multi-panel design. It's a complex enough relationship that a bit of shift in the door stiles just isn't noticeable.
I would order two 32" panels and move on. You'll never notice the extra inch or so of overlap after the first month because the side stiles stack. The situation certainly doesn't warrant cumbersome custom modifications.

The math works like this:    Rough opening =  61.75
                doors x 2 - 1 inch     =  58.625

                      difference       =   3.125

Add .75 door jamb and 1x4 to each side   =   3.00
                    overlap result     =   .875

This will be undetectable without a measuring device... and the easiest path.
The jamb can be shimmed to get you the exact 1 inch of overlap if needed. Normal door casing is 2.25 inches so everything will be covered.
